# webclient cannot download file with java spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-webclient

I plan to download some recording file from the given url. I have tested on postman before and proved that I can get binary file directly by sending get request to download_url with bearer token.
But when I use webclient to do this, I always get file with 0 size. Does any one can help?
This is code to download file

```
 Path path = Paths.get("src/main/resources/"+test+".bin");
        
        Flux<DataBuffer> dataBuffer = WebClient.create()
                .get()
                .uri(URI.create(download_url))
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, res -> res.bodyToMono(String.class)
                        .flatMap(errorMessage -> Mono.error(new CustException(errorMessage, res.statusCode().value()))))
                .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class);

        DataBufferUtils.write(dataBuffer, path,
                StandardOpenOption.CREATE)
                .share().block();
```

I didn't see any http exception and I did see file in destination. The request was succeed but file is empty.

Comment: it's worth trying to set/increase databuffer size

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are using `share().block()` but in general code looks ok. As with any other issues, creating minimal reproducible example (MRE) usually helps to identify the problem.

Here is a simplified unit test

```
@Test
void downloadFileTest() throws IOException {
    var downloadUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reactor/reactor-core/main/README.md";
    Path path = Paths.get("src/main/resources/test.bin");

    Flux<DataBuffer> dataBuffer = WebClient.create()
            .get()
            .uri(URI.create(downloadUrl))
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatusCode::isError, res -> res.bodyToMono(String.class)
                    .flatMap(errorMessage -> Mono.error(new RuntimeException(errorMessage))))
            .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class);

    var download = DataBufferUtils.write(dataBuffer, path, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);

    StepVerifier.create(download)
            .verifyComplete();

    assertTrue(Files.exists(path));
    assertTrue(Files.size(path) > 0);

    log.info("File: {} {}",  path, Files.size(path));
}
```

If you are using `WebClient` in non-reactive environment, you can still block and get the same result.

Comment: Thanks, I will try other ways to do it.